# I'm getting C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.2.2-8.0-vs16.dll error

Tags: php, runtime-error, xdebug

I am getting the following error for `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.2.2-8.0-vs16.dll`.

[image]

I have updated the php.ini file and checked it again and again.

[image]

```ini
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.2.2-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll"
```

Any idea how can I fix this error?

I tried the latest version of PHP and updated the php.ini file; dll file permission is fine.

Comment: Post code and errors as text, not screenshots.

Comment: Have you added the `php_xdebug-3.2.2-8.0-vs16.dll` from xdebug website to the location?

Comment: Hey Hassaan, Thanks for your feedback. I downloaded it and pasted it inside ext folder (xampp > php > ext)

Comment: Configuration code that I added in php.ini: 

xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.2.2-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll"

Answer (score 2):

You have downloaded the `php_xdebug-3.2.2-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll` file.

This has `nts` in the name, which stands for "non" thread safe.

Your PHP version string has `ZTS` in it.

NTS and ZTS are not compatible, and you need to download the right file from https://xdebug.org/download#releases — Xdebug uses `TS` for `ZTS` and *nothing* for `NTS` (the `N` stands for `no` or `non`).

You can also use [Xdebug's Wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard) to help you find the right file, and the right set of lines to put into `php.ini`.